# Doctrine 2 - Get all Records

Tags: doctrine-orm, orm

Does anyone know is there is a quick way to get all the records in a table using Doctrine with out using the DQL.

Did I miss something or did you need to just write the public function in the class?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you have an entity class ([Doctrine Repository manual](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/getting-started.html#entity-repositories)):

```
$records = $em->getRepository("Entities\YourTargetEntity")->findAll();
```

If you don't have entity class ([PDO manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)):

```
$pdo = $em->getCurrentConnection()->getDbh();
$result = $pdo->query("select * from table"); //plain sql query here, it's just PDO
$records = $pdo->fetchAll();
```

Comment: perfect thanks. The worked. I also found this helpful: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html

Comment: Poke: The Doctrine link is no longer valid !

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for poking. :) I've fixed the link, but I'd like to point out that SO allows anyone to edit anything. So, since you were concerned about the link and this answer in general, you were probably in a much better position to fix it than me, since I haven't used Doctrine since the link was valid - about 6 or 7 years from now.